# SilverStripe how to write to foreign relationship's field

Tags: php, orm, silverstripe

**What's the best way to write a form value to a foreign relationship's field?**

I need to save `$coachField`'s value into a specific column in a foreign table. IE: Within the `Team` object form I need to be able to save the `Coach`'s name *(which have a one-one relationship for the record)*.

I'm leaning towards using **onAfterWrite** in `Team` to get the coach's name, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the value in the first place and above all if this would be the best method.

**Current Dataobject**

```
class Team extends DataObject {

    // The value needs to be saved in Coach->Name
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Coach' => 'Coach'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        // The form field where to get the value from
        $coachField = TextField::create('CoachName', 'Who is the coach');

    }
}
```

**Foreign Dataobject**

```
class Coach extends DataObject {

    // Here's where the name should be written to
    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar'
    );

    private static $belongs_to = array(
        'Team' => 'Team'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 1:1 relation you can use [hasoneedit](https://github.com/stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit) module. The name of the field should be `HasOneName-_1_-FieldName` like

```
class Team extends DataObject {

    // The value needs to be saved in Coach->Name
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Coach' => 'Coach'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields(); //scaffold all fields

        // The form field where to get the value from
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('Coach-_1_-Name', 'Who is the coach');

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

It saves to the has_one relation auto-magically.